# ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists, Python3

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying this simple code in Python 3:

```
import mysql.connector
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conexion = mysql.connector.connect(user='?',
                                                password='?',
                                                host='?',
                                                db='?')
        self.cursor = self.conexion.cursor()
    def __del__(self):
        self.conexion.close()
        self.cursor.close() # The code works if i remove this line;

myApp = App()
```

The code works on Python 2 and in Python 3 if I remove the `self.cursor.close()` line. Is this supposed to happen ?

The problem is when I try to use `self.cursor.close()` inside the `__del__` ,the code works if `self.cursor.close()` is inside the `__init__`, otherwise, I can even create tables.

The error I am experiencing is:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method MySQL_App.__del__ of <__main__.MySQL_App object at 0x7f6f87f42278>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filename.py", line 22, in __del__
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 338, in close
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 310, in _have_unread_result
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Comment: why are you defining `__del__()`?  That's highly unusual.

Comment: I need to close the connections at end. I think the best way to do that is with `__del__()`(isn't `__del__` used in same situations like a destructor ?)

Comment: Ok, i changed `__del__()` to `End()` and for some reason it just works...

Comment: After some research, I found that cursor is garbage collected by python, so isn't necessary to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the wrong way around. Since you create the cursor *after* the connection, you need to close it *before* the connection.

```
self.cursor.close()
self.conexion.close()
```